# How, with Angular's jQueryLite, to find an element by id?

Tags: angularjs

I need to know if an element `id="Tags"` is present in my Angular's controller document....

So I do the check (immediate window debug results):

```
?angular.element($document).find("#Tags").length
0
?$("#Tags").length
1
?angular.element($document.querySelector('#Tags'))
VM1119:1 Uncaught TypeError: $document.querySelector is not a function
```

Just wondering, how to make jQueryLite to find an element by id...

Comment: With the AngularJS framework, one generally uses an [attribute directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on the element of interest. The element is then available in the postLink function as `element[0]` or the directive controller as `$element[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. But you can use vanilla JavaScript

```
var el = document.getElementById("Tags");
```

And you can turn the result into a jqLite selection

```
angular.element(el);
```